# Android: Impossible upload image to remote MySql DB with php script

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, upload

I spent 2 weeks on this problem. I wrote the code below (Android and php). It seems ok but not working or not working well. The client Android seems send something The server side receive something but i don't know what it is .

Below the code on the client Android and on the server.

Thanks.

```
…
Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new    ContentValues());
uri_Target=uriTarget.toString();
OutputStream imageFileOS;
try 
{
imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
imageFileOS.write(arg0);
imageFileOS.flush();
imageFileOS.close();

Toast.makeText(ActSismicoCamera_New.this, "Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("percorso",uri_Target);            
editor.commit(); 
inviaPosizione(uri_Target); 
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{           
e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{           
e.printStackTrace();
}
camera.startPreview();
}
…
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void inviaPosizione(String percorso)
{
InputStream is=null;
try
{
String uri_Target;
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
uri_Target = preferences.getString("percorso", null);          
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(uri_Target);          
String filenamelastPhoto;
filenamelastPhoto = getLastImage(imageUri);        
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+ "/DCIM/Camera/");
File immagine = new File(directory, filenamelastPhoto); //or any other format supported
if(immagine.exists()) 
{
 Toast.makeText(ActSismicoCamera_New.this, "ESISTE = "+immagine, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(immagine.toString()); 
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try
{                  
  bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bao);             
  byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
  Toast.makeText(ActSismicoCamera_New.this, "inviaPosizione Valore ba= " + ba, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  int flag = 1;
  String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba,flag);
  ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag","registra"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("media",ba1));
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Custom user agent");
  HttpPost httppost = new
  HttpPost("http://xxxxx.org/AndActSismicoUploadFile.php");
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               is = entity.getContent();
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               Toast.makeText(ActSismicoCamera_New.this, "inviaPosizione Exception su HttpClient: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           try 
           {
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String line = null;
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
       {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
       }
       is.close();
       json = sb.toString();                         
    } 
            catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

     }
     catch (Exception e) 
{           
       e.printStackTrace();
}               
}
```

PHP Script

```
<?php     
require_once 'DB_Funzioni.php';
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') 
{  
$tag = $_POST['tag'];
$oggetto = $_POST['media'];

if (isset($_POST['media'])) 
    {   
    header('Content-Type: bitmap;charset-utf-8');                       
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media"]["tmp_name"],"immagini/" . $_FILES["media"]["name"])) 
    {
        echo "The file ". $_FILES['media']['name']." has been uploaded";
        $info="The file ". basename( $_FILES['media']['name'])." has been uploaded";
        mail ($destinatario, $ogg, $info);
    }
    else
    {
        $info="Problema!";
        mail ($destinatario, $ogg, $info);
        switch ($_FILES['media']['error'])
        {  
                    case 1:
        echo "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini";
        $info="The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini!";
        mail ($destinatario, $ogg, $info);
        break;
        case 2:
        echo "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form";
        $info="The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form!";
        mail ($destinatario, $ogg, $info);
        break;
        case 3:
        echo "Only part of the file was uploaded";                     
        $info="Only part of the file was uploaded!";
        mail ($destinatario, $ogg, $info);
        break;
        case 4:
        echo "No file was uploaded";
        $info="No file was uploaded!";
        mail ($destinatario, $ogg, $info);
        break;             
        case 6:
        echo "Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3";
        $info="Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3!";
        mail ($destinatario, $ogg, $info);
        break; 
        case 7:
        echo "Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0";
        $info="Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0!";
        mail ($destinatario, $ogg, $info);
        break;
        case 8:
        echo "A PHP extension stopped the file upload";
        $info="A PHP extension stopped the file upload!";
        mail ($destinatario, $ogg, $info);
        break;                       
        }
    }

    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);
        $db = new DB_Functions();       
    $fileName = $_FILES['media']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['media']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['media']['type'];       
    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media"]["tmp_name"],"immagini/" . $_FILES["media"]["name"]);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }       
    $file = $db->storeFile($fileName);  
    if ($file)
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        //$response["filename"]["id"] = $file["filename"];
        $response["filename"]= $tmpName ;
        echo json_encode($response);
            } 
    Else
    {
                 // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = 1;
                //$response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Insert";
                $response["error_msg"] = mysql_error();
                echo json_encode($response);
        }
  }
  Else
    {
               $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);                  
                $response["error"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Media vuoto";                 
                echo json_encode($response);
        }            
}
//mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: always a pleasure to see non-English variable names... this makes reading code so wonderful easy and understandable...

Comment: Why not get it to dump whatever it is getting and maybe SERVER variables down to a file for debugging?

Comment: I use an external service provider. How can I do this ?

Comment: it could not work because for pictures you need the content type multipart ... in android maybe "MultiPartEntity"? See:
http://useandgain.blogspot.de/2012/06/uploading-image-from-androidjava-using.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer ... i will complete this answer as we go ...

First I would recommend you to check if you are getting the post data you are supposed to be getting. Please insert this on the top after:

```
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') 
{
```

...

```
file_put_contents ("mydebugdata.txt",json_encode($_POST));
```

this should dump the data the script is recieving to the file "mydebugdata.txt" ...
json_encode() gives the $_POST some structure ... so you can read the data...

then try saving a picture and post the contents of mydebugdata.txt here ...